Find most abundant transcript isoform of a gene across different tissues in long read RNA-Seq data
I want to understand which is the most abundant variant of a gene of interest across different tissues by looking at different publicly available databases (mouse/human). I have deduced from literature and discussions that I need long read data datasets for this kind of analysis. I came across ENCODE project from where I can download long read datasets. I thought of running IsoQuant. However, there are a few questions on how to perform this kind of analysis downstream of running this tool:

can I perform direct comparisons between tissues?
will I have to normalize across datasets before comparison?
how do I perform this normalization?
are there any other publicly available databases that you would suggest to look for this transcript isoforms?

If there are any better ways to address this query please let me know.
